# How to iterate through a list with nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested-loops, nested-lists

So i have a list with nested dictionaries inside them and what i want to do is read the values of views from the dictionaries and put them through a multiplier.

```
video_ads=({'title': 'Healthy Living', 'company': 'Health Promotion 
Board','views': 15934},
{'title': 'Get a ride, anytime anywhere', 'company': 'Uber', 'views': 
923834},
{'title': 'Send money with GrabPay', 'company': 'Grab', 'views': 23466},
{'title': 'Ubereats now delivers nationwide', 'company': 'Uber', 'views': 
1337},
{'title': 'Get cabs now with UberFlash', 'company': 'Uber', 'views': 90234})
```

so what i am trying to do is get the title together with the views mulitiplied by a certain factor, this is what i've written so far

```
def payment_for_views(x):
    for x in range(0,5):
        x = x+1

        if video_ads[x]['views'] >= 50000:
            payment = video_ads[x]['views']*0.55
        elif views <50000 and video_ads[x]['views'] >=10000:
            payment=video_ads[x]['views']*0.68
        else:
            payment = video_ads[x]['views']*0.82
    #print(x)
    print(video_ads[x]['title'] + ': $'+ str(payment))
    print(video_ads[x]['title'] + ': $'+ str(payment))
    print(video_ads[x]['title'] + ': $'+ str(payment))
    print(video_ads[x]['title'] + ': $'+ str(payment))
    print(video_ads[x]['title'] + ': $'+ str(payment))
```

But it seems to be printing only one line for example:

```
 Get cabs now with UberFlash: $49628.700000000004
 Get cabs now with UberFlash: $49628.700000000004
 Get cabs now with UberFlash: $49628.700000000004
 Get cabs now with UberFlash: $49628.700000000004
 Get cabs now with UberFlash: $49628.700000000004
```

that is all i get. I need 5 lines all of them with the various titles and various amounts. Help!!! and thanks in advance!

Comment: indent your print statement in the for loop. it is only printing one object because `x = 5` always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place your `print` statement within your `for` loop.

Leaving `print` after and outside your loop means that `x` will be fixed at the final value set in the `for` loop.

```
def payment_for_views(x):
    for x in range(len(x)):
        if video_ads[x]['views'] >= 50000:
            payment = video_ads[x]['views']*0.55
        elif video_ads[x]['views'] <50000 and video_ads[x]['views'] >=10000:
            payment=video_ads[x]['views']*0.68
        else:
            payment = video_ads[x]['views']*0.82
        print(video_ads[x]['title'] + ': $'+ str(payment))
```

There are a number of ways you can improve your code:

1. Iterate your dictionaries directly rather than by index.
2. Extract the "views" value once for each dictionary and assign to a variable.
3. Use chained comparisons for checking whether a value is between two others.
4. Use f-strings (Python 3.6+) with decimal precision specified.

Here's a demo:

```
def payment_for_views(x):
    for item in x:
        views = item['views']
        if views >= 50000:
            factor = 0.55
        elif 10000 <= views < 50000:
            factor = 0.68
        else:
            factor = 0.82

        print(f'{item["title"]}: ${views*factor:.2f}')

payment_for_views(video_ads)
```

Result:

```
Healthy Living: $10835.12
Get a ride, anytime anywhere: $508108.70
Send money with GrabPay: $15956.88
Ubereats now delivers nationwide: $1096.34
Get cabs now with UberFlash: $49628.70
```

Comment: thank you my good sir, i played around with the indentation of my last print function to get it inside the for loop and it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

```
video_ads=({'title': 'Healthy Living', 'company': 'Health Promotion Board','views': 15934},
           {'title': 'Get a ride, anytime anywhere', 'company': 'Uber', 'views': 923834},
           {'title': 'Send money with GrabPay', 'company': 'Grab', 'views': 23466},
           {'title': 'Ubereats now delivers nationwide', 'company': 'Uber', 'views': 1337},
           {'title': 'Get cabs now with UberFlash', 'company': 'Uber', 'views': 90234})

def payment_for_views(item):
    if item >= 50000:
        payment = item * 0.55
    elif item < 50000 and item >= 10000:
        payment = item * 0.68
    else:
        payment = item * 0.82
    return payment

[print(per_ad['title'], ': $' + str(payment_for_views(per_ad['views']))) for per_ad in video_ads]
```

Output:

> Healthy Living : $10835.12
>
> Get a ride, anytime anywhere : $508108.70000000007
>
> Send money with GrabPay : $15956.880000000001
>
> Ubereats now delivers nationwide : $1096.34
>
> Get cabs now with UberFlash : $49628.700000000004

Answer (score 0):

```
for a in video_ads:
    print('%s: $%.2f' % (a['title'], a['views'] * (0.55 if a['views'] >= 50000 else 0.68 if a['views'] >= 10000 else 0.82)))
```

This outputs:

```
Healthy Living: $10835.12
Get a ride, anytime anywhere: $508108.70
Send money with GrabPay: $15956.88
Ubereats now delivers nationwide: $1096.34
Get cabs now with UberFlash: $49628.70
```